# How to persist DatetTime with time zone in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I hava a MySQL using UTC timezone and try to save an CakePHP Entity to a datettime column in the database.

When the PHP DatetTime object has a timezone (that differs from UTC) CakePHP does not convert the value to UTC during save.

I wrote a short test to demonstrate the problem.

```php
public function testTryCreateReservation(): void
{
    $e = $this->Reservations->newEmptyEntity();
    $now = new \DateTime();
    $start = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Vienna')); 
    $start->setTimestamp($now->getTimestamp());
    $end = new \DateTime('now'); 
    $end->setTimestamp($now->getTimestamp());
    $e->start_time = $start;

    $a = $this->Reservations->get($a->id);
    $this->assertEquals($end, $a->end_time);
    $this->assertEquals($start, $a->start_time); // this fails
}
```

Here is the phpunit output

```
Failed asserting that two DateTime objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-2020-09-02T07:54:45.000000+0200
+2020-09-02T07:54:45.000000+0000
```

Shouldn't CakePHP convert the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Enabling timezone conversion

The ORM will convert the timezone when the column is a `datetime` type, and you configure the database timezone on the respective database type instance (`\Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType`).

You can do this in your `bootstrap.php`, there's a section at the bottom showing how to build and configure database types:

```php
\Cake\Database\TypeFactory::build('datetime')->setDatabaseTimezone('UTC');
```

It should also be noted that this will also enable the conversion the other way around, ie from the database timezone to the application's default timezone (`App.defaultTimezone`)! If you don't want that, you can disable it via the `setKeepDatabaseTimezone()` method:

```php
\Cake\Database\TypeFactory::build('datetime')->setKeepDatabaseTimezone(true);
```

The objects will then be created with (*not* converted to) the timezone that is configured for the database type.

I guess it wouldn't hurt if there were a dedicated section about database timezone conversion somewhere in the Cookbook.

### Applying timezone conversion to specific columns only

Note that you can also map a new type and assign it to specific table columns only, in case you don't want this to apply globally:

```php
// in your bootstrap.php
\Cake\Database\TypeFactory::map('customDateTime', \Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType::class);
\Cake\Database\TypeFactory::build('customDateTime')->setDatabaseTimezone('UTC');

// in the table class where you want this type to apply to a specific column
protected function _initializeSchema(\Cake\Database\Schema\TableSchemaInterface $schema): \Cake\Database\Schema\TableSchemaInterface
{
    $schema->setColumnType('column_name', 'customDateTime');

    return $schema;
}
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Data Types > DateTime Type](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#datetime-type)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Adding Custom Types](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types)**

Comment: Thanks so far. `setDatabaseTimezone('UTC')` seems to work. But then what´s  _Datasource.default.timezone_ for? This sounds like having a separate setting for cake internal time conversion (of created and modified dates) and user space datetime fields. Is that the case?

Comment: @GerdK That's the database connection's timezone configuration, it is completely separated from CakePHP's date/time functionality. It affects timezone aware DBMS functionality, for example `NOW()` generating dates in the given timezone, or on MySQL the `TIMESTAMP` column type which converts from the session timezone to UTC for storage and vice versa for retrieval. The point of CakePHP's conversion layer is cross-db compatibility, centralization of timezone conversion, and therefore less points of failure.

Comment: @GerdK From my experience you're usually best of by following the "_one timezone to rule them all_" approach, where you store everything in UTC, and convert in the application when required.